# Erro ao adicionar appcompat-v7 api level 22

Tags: android, android-studio, app-compat-v7

estou tentando adicionar o appcompat-v7 ao meu projeto, porém quando sincronizo com o `gradle` ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
/path/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values/values.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "layout" has already been defined
```

Segue meu build.gradle onde só adicionei a linha `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`

```
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é realmente o descrito no erro, encontrei no arquivo `res/values/attr.xml` o segunte trecho de código

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomListView">
    <attr name="layout" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comentei este código e Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Não testei tua configuração, mas o problema pode ser o `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`.
Passe para a versão que você está trabalhando `22.2.1`

Sugiro também que você utilize a nova versão, a 23. Tive alguns problemas com o appCompat nesta versão que você está tentando utilizar. Boa sorte

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
```